# Библиотека для Android для отображения тэгов c переносом на новую строку

Tags: android, library

Может кто встречал, чтобы сделать как на картинке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PS: сразу оговорюсь, я понимаю, что это можно сделать самому. Но я делать не хочу :) Это не такое критичное, чтобы тратить время на эту вьюху.

UPD1: На данный момент посоветовали либу [TagView](https://github.com/Cutta/TagView). И так неплохой ресурс - [android-arsenal.com](http://android-arsenal.com/).

UPD2: это TagView - просто тихий ужас.

UPD3: хочешь что-то сделать, сделай это сам. В общем обошёлся FlexboxLayout + группа TextView с своим бекграундом.

Comment: Ребята я первым делом поискал и в гугле и на гитхабе, но честно, почему-то не додумался, что надо искать по слову tag.

Comment: Честно, не понимаю, за что тут столько минусов. Есть задача, нужен инструмент. Вроде как половина вопросов про [tag:android] касается поиска библиотеки или класса.

Comment: можно еще использовать либу от гугла, правда стилизовать придется элементы самому, но вот перенос строк и многие другие типы отображения имеются. обзор возможностей есть в серии статей https://habrahabr.ru/company/speakasap/blog/300908/

Comment: @YShinkarev не обращайте внимания. тут иногда встречаются люди, которые считают что вместо того, чтобы написать ответ, лучше послать в гугл. О том, что гугл их при этом выведет на SO, где кто-то когда-то не поленился и написал ответ - они не задумываются. Просто ставьте тревогу "неконструктивный" на подобные комментарии.

Comment: Обновился первый пост.

Comment: Библиотека FlowLayout -
 https://github.com/nex3z/FlowLayout